# Jquery hide all elements that are not in array

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input

Is it possible to hide all elements that are NOT in an array using Jquery?

I have over 40 inputs/selects on a form and I want to hide some of them when I use a select on the form.

```js
$("#type").on('change', function() {
      if ($("#type").val() === "Blue") {
        var elements = [$("#id-element"), $(".class-element), ... , ... ]; // these elements should be visible and the remaining elements on the form I want to hide them.
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='type'>
        <option> Blue </option>
        <option> Red </option>
    </select>
```

Comment: you have used name like id attribute here... $("#type")

Comment: I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: No idea what elements need to be hidden . Provide a [mcve] that represents your basic use case

Comment: It doesnt matter what element i want to hide. Multiple classes elements and id`s.

Comment: Put the selectors in that array `selectors`, not the jQuery select statements. Then you can go `$("*").not(selectors.join(',')).hide();` which will resolve to `$("*").not("#id-element, .class-element, ...").hide();`

Comment: I don't exactely understand what you want to do here, but here is a fiddle of what I think, you could wan't to accomplish:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88n7ffv1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's `not`

```js
$("#type").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "Blue") {
  
  //note that this is a single string with comma sepreating between different selectors
    var elements = "#id-element,.class-element";

    //select all inputs
    $("input").not(elements).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='type'>
        <option> select one </option>
        <option> Blue </option>
        <option> Red </option>
</select>
<br />
<input id="id-element" value="#id-element" /><br />
<input class="class-element" value=".class-element" /><br />
<input id="other-id" value="#other-id" /><br />
<input class="other-class" value=".other-class" /><br />
```